# Repair python2.7 installation on Ubuntu after manually overwriting elements in /usr/

Tags: python, ubuntu, apt

I downloaded the latest ParaView from [here](https://www.paraview.org/download/) and thought it would be clever to integrate the directory structure inside the tar.gz to my /usr/ directory using

```
sudo tar -xzvf ParaView-5.4.1-Qt5-OpenGL2-MPI-Linux-64bit.tar.gz -C /usr/ --strip-components=1
```

Paraview runs fine, but after todays reboot my guake terminal refused to launch

```
~> guake
   /usr/bin/python2: No module named guake
```

Obviously, my python installation is completely broken :( I tried reinstalling `guake`, `python-dev` and so on, nothing helps. Even running `pip` fails and points at a problem in the `ctypes`-module:

```
~> pip install --upgrade pip
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/ctypes/__init__.py", line 10, in <module>
        from _ctypes import Union, Structure, Array
    ImportError: /usr/lib/python2.7/_ctypes.so: undefined symbol: 
    PyUnicodeUCS2_FromUnicode
```

Checking the Paraview tar.gz revealed that the ctypes module is really included and untaring overwrote it. *I really need some help here!*

Thanks in advance.

---

## Edit

Based on the comments of @BoboDarph, I tried to build python from source using the same version and installing to /usr. This is the install script:

```
!#/bin/bash

sudo apt-get install build-essential checkinstall
sudo apt-get install libreadline-gplv2-dev libncursesw5-dev libssl-dev libsqlite3-dev tk-dev libgdbm-dev libc6-dev libbz2-dev

version=2.7.11
wget https://www.python.org/ftp/python/$version/Python-$version.tgz

tar -xvf Python-$version.tgz
cd Python-$version

./configure --prefix=/usr
make profile-opt
sudo checkinstall
```

Since checkinstall failed to install the resulting package because files of existing packages would have been overwritten, I forced the install using

```
sudo dpkg --force-overwrite --install python_2.7.11-1_amd64.deb
```

`pip` is now working again, but guake did not work even after reinstalling. It now seems things are really broken and I can't figure out how to fix. E.g. running

```
sudo aptitude reinstall python-dev
```

now suggest to remove almost all package of the system to resolve conflicts, see [pastebin](https://pastebin.com/CiaRSCq2).

**Any help to rescue my system is highly appreciated!**

Comment: I think you can purge the existing python installation with sudo dpkg -P python2.7 and then re-install it with sudo apt-get install python2.7. I suggest that because if I remember correctly, pip needs a working python install to properly work.

Comment: Thanks @BoboDarph. Somehow it sounds a bit vague which makes me hesitate: I really don't want to crash my system completely. Will it be safe?

Comment: Not necessarily. If you do apt-get autoremove after the purge, you will most likely remove all packages related to python from your system which will most likely render it unusable. So don't. The purge of python 2.7 alone should be safe enough, provided you manage to properly install it afterwards.

Comment: sudo apt-get install --reinstall python2.7 might also work. I've only used the purge/reinstall option to fix installations on vmware machines I didnt care about.

Comment: @BoboDarph I dared, but `sudo dpkg -P python2.7` does not proceed due to dependencies. `sudo apt-get install --reinstall python2.7` did not solve the problem either. Any further ideas?

Comment: Try an installation from source? https://askubuntu.com/questions/101591/how-do-i-install-the-latest-python-2-7-x-or-3-x-on-ubuntu

Comment: @BoboDarph now I compiled from source as you suggested which caused that I now have another python installation under /usr/local and all dependencies seem to be completly broken now! `sudo aptitude reinstall guake` gives a whole bunch of info now, suggesting to remove almost all packages of my system, including gnome-shell. I'm helpless now and fear to reboot :(

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/153606/discussion-between-physicspyuser-and-bobodarph).